# Inhabitant of a hospital?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that can describe a long-term inhabitant (inhabitant is the best I've come up with so far) of a hospital.

Specifically, a soldier living (retained? - again, word might fit here too) in a War Hospital not long after the First World War, however the answer doesn't have to take into account the time period, as I feel there is a word at the back of my mind I simply cannot find right now which means "inhabitant of hospital."

I'd like to be able to use it to complete this sentence:

> The gravel pathway was bordered by short, waist-height shrubberies behind which were the colourful flowerbeds intended to pacify the hospital's ________.

Comment: Is the word similar (by sound perhaps) to attendants? Just thought of this, but it also isn't the correct word.

Comment: "long-term care residents" would fit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[*inmate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inmate)**:

> any of a group occupying a single place of residence; especially :  a
>   person confined (as in a prison or hospital) (Merriam Webster)

In a hospital setting, the word currently has a strong connotation of referring to patients with mental disorders. It might sound strange if most of the people in the hospital are being held there for other reasons.

[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/inmate) also has a short explanation of the meaning and connotations of the word, where it says "You can talk about a hospital inmate or the inmates at a local boarding school, but it's most common to use inmate and prisoner interchangeably."

Comment: While I'll admit this is technically correct, I don't think the fact that it made me laugh is necessarily a good thing. :)

Comment: Hah hah! Yes, thank you! @CandiedOrange perhaps not necessarily a good thing, but in the passage I'm writing it does convey the feeling I want to put across.

Comment: @CandiedOrange: Yes, it might not be the best choice! However, I think it implies imprisonment more than the other words suggested so far.

Comment: Check or no check, in the US, at least, inmate is just about never used in a hospital context, even a psychological hospital.  Patient is the correct term, and if it's a long term care hospital, perhaps resident.

Comment: @StevenLittman Good point, though [residents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residency_%28medicine%29) might disagree with *resident* in that context. Also, because the OP used "retained", I had the impression that the soldier was resident in a professional capacity, not as a patient.

Comment: While this might work specifically for the OP's case, it is an *extremely* nonstandard choice. @theonlygusti You would only use this is you are *intentionally* trying to portray the situation as extremely negative, where the person is held against their will and generally treated very badly. It might also be used to more convey the speaker's or the patient's opinion of the situation, and in a more metaphorical sense than everyday speech.

Comment: This answer is wrong, at least in American English. Here, an inmate is someone in jail/prison, and the only time you'd use it to describe an inpatient or long-term care patient is if you were trying to call the hospital a prison, in a metaphorical sense.

Comment: @jpmc26 Which is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Inmate in a hospital, to me, pretty much implies someone held against their will for psychiatric treatment (or prison inmates with serious medical conditions). "Patients" fits best in the blank given, though you could say something like "unhappy patients" or "discontent patients" or "disgruntled patients" to communicate the patients' unhappiness.

Comment: @theonlygusti While I have answered differently below your use of 'pacify' brings to mind a completely different type of patient.  Given the broad outline for the time in question perhaps either **traumatized** or **shell shocked** would fit.  see: http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/worldwars/wwone/shellshock_01.shtml

Comment: Whilst doing voluntary work at a psychiatric hospital, 20 years ago, I was specifically told to refer to them as "clients", not "patients". However, I've found "inmate" is in common use for a psych hospital, and it fits given that they were there against their will. But you wouldn't use this word for, say, an old people's care home.

Answer (score 39):

***[Inpatient](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inpatient)***:

> - A patient who is admitted to a hospital or clinic for treatment that requires at least one overnight stay.

(AHD)

Comment: I realise now that my question does not express everything I want to convey with my word choice, and although sumelic's answer better fits my needs, this answer is the best answer to my original question, so I will upvote.

Comment: Hmm, "inpatient" exists to distinguish from "outpatient". Put it this way: it's rather like saying "overnight patient".  I wouldn't use it to refer to residents.  (Note that indeed residents in a mental hospital, and residents in a long-term care facility, are not referred to as "inpatients".)

Answer (score 19):

I'm not sure "inmate" - the accepted answer - is the typical English term. At least not for Britsh English. A more typical term, particularly for First World War would be "resident patient".

There is even a Sherlock Holmes story titled [The Adventure of the Resident Patient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventure_of_the_Resident_Patient).

Comment: Your answer is also pretty much correct for American English. The only difference in everyday American usage would be that you would typically omit the "patient" part. A permanent inhabitant of a medical facility is simply a "resident." (This primarily comes from nursing homes and assisted living facilities, but when a hospital is acting in the same capacity that a nursing home would, this fits.)

Comment: "Resident" usually means a junior doctor.

Comment: @SteveBennett Also, yes. The short form in either case is only used when the context makes the longer form unnecessary, so it's not actually a vocabulary conflict.

Answer (score 6):

'Patient(s)' would probably be the best word - [see dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/patient).

Comment: Perhaps, but in my mind I had a word that also reflected the fact that these men could be seen perhaps as prisoners, kept there against their will.

Comment: @theonlygusti.  (1) the answer is "patient". (2) you say *"I had a word that also reflected the fact that these men could be seen perhaps as prisoners, kept there against their will"* So, that is a different separate question.

Answer (score 6):

Common use in our area differentiates between (and provides differently constructed and staffed facilities for) an acute-care patient and a long-term care patient. But the single word really is 'patient' in either case.

I suppose you could also use 'resident' for a patient at a long-term care facility.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Answers here are expected to include citations (see the other answers for examples); more in the help.

Comment: I've definitely heard *resident* used in this way, in the sense of "a person who resides in a place." It does have the issue of being a bit ambiguous with "a physician who joins the medical staff of a hospital as a salaried employee for a specified period to gain advanced training usually in a particular field". Both from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/resident?s=t).

Answer (score 5):

The correct term for this is **inpatient**. Someone with an acute condition undergoing long-term treatment is not considered an *inmate* as mentioned above, that's certainly a term that would *never* be used in a medical environment.

> **inpatient** - *noun* - 
>   a patient who lives in hospital while under treatment.

'Patient' is also an acceptable term, because a person seeing out the end of their days in Palliative care (for instance) would still be referred to as a 'Patient' in a casual conversation (even though they effectively live in the hospital), or an 'inpatient' on the documentation.

Source: Nearly a decade working in ICU/CCU

Comment: I'll drop a comment in here to follow up on this also - at least in Australia, even a convicted felon undergoing treatment under armed supervision is still referred to a patient, even if they have been an inmate in prison before being transferred for treatment. Same goes for court-mandated mental health confinement... The person is still an Inpatient even if the court has sentenced them to confinement in a mental health facility. For the purpose of your prose, you might want to say *"Even as an inpatient, he felt more like an inmate"*, if that's the idea you want to convey.

Comment: This answer appeared eight hours after its counterpart. Please don't give duplicate answers: upvote and comment (if you have enough rep to comment).

Comment: I mainly expanded on this, as the highest voted (*at the time) and 'correct' answer is completely incorrect. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

[***internee***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=%22hospital%27s+internees%22&oq=%22hospital%27s+internees%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...3371.16950.0.17349.23.22.0.0.0.0.979.1663.5-1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..21.0.0.0.nlB398mvO38#q=%22hospital+internees%22)

> One who is interned or confined, especially in wartime.
>
> [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/internee)
>
> *The Commission requested that, given the information received describing the inhuman and degrading sanitary conditions in the hospital, which put the health of the **hospital internees** in grave risk* [...]
>
> [CUP](https://books.google.fr/books?id=H2KQJlap18gC&pg=PA368&dq=%22hospital+internees%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi21-Do74TMAhWHXhoKHX_HA_AQ6AEIMTAD#v=onepage&q=%22hospital%20internees%22&f=false)

[***confinee***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22hospital+confinees%22&prmd=minv&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFu7i6l4bMAhXHBywKHXo0CVAQ_AUIDCgG&biw=633&bih=415)

> A person held in confinement.
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/confinee)

[***detainee***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22mealy+mouthed+politician%22&biw=1024&bih=672&prmd=vni&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAnoajkobMAhWFbBoKHV2xDnEQ_AUIBCgA&dpr=2#q=%22hospital+detainee%22)

> *Detainee* is a term used by certain governments and their armed forces to refer to individuals held in custody, such as those it does not classify and treat as either prisoners of war or suspects in criminal cases. It is used to refer to "any person captured or otherwise detained by an armed force."
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detention_(imprisonment))

Comment: This is unlikely to be used in the context of a normal hospital.